# show stereotype application in eclipse uml, after closing diagram

Tags: eclipse, uml, eclipse-emf, stereotype

> How can I show stereotypes inline again?

When I create an uml model in eclipse, I can apply stereotypes, no problem:
[image: before]

But when I close this diagram and reopen it, I get this:

[image: after close and reopen]

I understand WHY this is, uml models are saved in 2 parts. But how do I show the stereotypes inline again? on my modeling elements like before. (I want to extend my model)

Comment: please have a look whether the profile (found in the tree further below) containing your stereotypes is properly loaded (found) by the editor and report back

Comment: Hi, yes it is. under the platform:/resource/ (model), there a similar link: platform:/resource/..(profile) to the profile. I can see all the stereotypes.

Comment: Also when I reopen it now, some of the stereotypes are applied, and some are not.. A combination of figure 1 & 2..

Comment: Well, it could possibly be caused by different versions of the ecore representations found in the eAnnotations at the top of the uml file. If you can reproduce the problem with a new profile and model you should report it on the eclipse uml tracker.

Comment: I did change the UML profile while creating the model, I guess its because of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problems occurs when you define your own UML profile in eclipse, while simultaneously testing it with an UML model. 
When you adjust the profile, a new "version" is created. But the model created to test the profile still refers to the old version.